# application failed to create folder when other application occupy it

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, mkdirs

This is my question.

First I have create my personal folder on create

```
File parentFolder = new File(MainApplication.getInstance().getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator+"myfolder");
    if (!parentFolder.exists()) {
        parentFolder.mkdirs();
    }
```

Second in my application,i can receive file such as png from another application,and the file that i received has been saved in /Android/data/packageName/cache/myfolder/hashcode/example.png. And i choose the gallery to open it from intent chooser.

When gallery is open and I can see the png file.I kill my application's process and uninstall it.

Finally I install my application again.The path /Android/data/packageName doesn't been created! And create function show that

```
MainApplication.getInstance().getExternalCacheDir();
```

returns null!

Give me some advise! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
new Context().getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: This method is not used. No matter how to getExternalCacheDir() will return null.Because app does not create path for some reason

Comment: So instead of cache you can use the file folder/directory. Anyways cache folder will delete its files automatically when device is on low storage.

Comment: i know it ,but i need to delete the files and folders i received or created at onDestroy()